# Convert UK date to US date in PHP with different separator

Tags: php

How would you convert UK date to US date in PHP without much regard to separator:

e.g.

```
01/01/2012

to 

2012-01-01
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is ISO date; US would be MM/DD/YYYY.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't have to invoke date and time functions, don't do it and according to your question it seems like you only need string manipulations. Use sscanf()

```
list($date,$month,$year) = sscanf("01/01/2012", "%d/%d/%d");
echo "$month-$date-$year";
```

Comment: If you'd like leading a zero on your day and month here's a website explaining how. 
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=7705 

Here's how I used the above and link ... 

`list($date,$month,$year) = sscanf("01/01/2012", "%02s/%02s/%04s");`

`echo "$year-$month-$date";`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `strtotime` but that's a magical function so I don't trust it.

A more discreet approach is to just do a very manual conversion, like:

```
$us_date = "01/01/2012";
$parts = explode("/", $us_date, 3);
$uk_date = $parts[2] . "-" . $parts[0] . "-" . $parts[1]; // flip day and month?
```

Comment: Interesting! You might want to switch around the $us_date and $uk_date variables tho!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$format1 = strtotime("01/01/2012");
//$format2 = strtotime("2012-01-01");
echo date("Y-m-d",$format1);
?>
```

Comment: `strtotime()` assumes `mm/dd/yyyy` when using slashes, which is not the British method, so this would produce the wrong result for `4/3/2012` (4 March 2012) because `strtotime` would read that as 3 April.