# why is this strtotime echoing wrong output for english date input?

Tags: php

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('02-12-13'));
```

It's english format so

Expected  output: `2013-12-02`

My output: `2002-12-13`

Any one knows what's going on?

Comment: It's interpreting "02-12-13" as YY-MM-DD.

Comment: Because `strtotime` isn't magic and "dd-dd-dd" is about as ambiguous as it can possibly get. Consult the manual for what formats are explicitly supported.

Comment: it should not. according to specs, it is english (dd-mm-yy) if there's a dash. And I don't know why someone would give it a minus vote.

Comment: In this context, the word English refers to the language when interpreting things like `strtotime("next tuesday")` -- it's not referring to American-style date formatting.

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php ( Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.).

Comment: Please post the link to where you are looking. According to the docs [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) two examples are given with the format XX-XX-XX. Both of these examples are in the format of YY-MM-DD.

Comment: It's in the strtotime documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), 4th note. Very curious. Of course, why use 2-digits for year? Did we not learn anything from Y2K?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paramter to strtotime is parsed as `yy "-" MM "-" DD` format when you specify the year with only two digits.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php (in the ISO8601 notations).

If you specify the year with four digits, i.e., `02-12-2013`, you should get your expected result.

Comment: however the following is ambigious.Look at php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php ( Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.).

Comment: Hmmm, you have a point, I guess the documentation is conflicting in that the note says this while the description of the function refers to the date formats on the linked datetime formats page, where the only interpretation for xx-xx-xx is yy-MM-DD.  However, the note seems to be the wrong thing (see also the comment on the docs page far down by viper7 at viper-7 dot com.

Answer (score 1):

"xx-xx-xx" is interpreted as "yy-mm-dd", as specified in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to use date_parse_from_format () and use the returned array to build the correct format.

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php

however, maybe it is better to just format your original us date string with simple string manipulation.

[Convert UK date to US date in PHP with different separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550688/convert-uk-date-to-us-date-in-php-with-different-separator)

```
list($date,$month,$year) = sscanf("01/01/2012", "%d/%d/%d");
echo "$month-$date-$year";
```

Comment: This seems like a lot of overhead. Just change your date format to match the format `strtotime` is expecting...

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat()  is great but doesn't work for older phps and my server has php <5.3